# Disabling tab discarding in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using Chrome version 48.0.2564.23 beta-m (64-bit) and I wanted to disable tab discarding. Elsewhere on the internet people say there is a flag for this (chrome://flags/#enable-tab-discarding) but I cannot find it. Has this option been disabled, renamed? Is it still possible to disable tab discarding?

Comment: It's there for me and disabled by default in version 47.0.2526.80. My only suggestion is you downgrade if it's causing issues for you :/

Comment: As stated in the answer, it can be disabled, but using a command line option. I prefer not to downgrade

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and finally found a flag named “**automatic-tab-discarding**” (chrome://flags/#automatic-tab-discarding). So I think the previous flag “enable-tab-discarding” has simply been renamed once the tab discarding behavior was made the default. Which makes sense.

I'd really prefer it to be a regular Chrome option though, instead of an unguaranteed-to-remain-functional flag.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`--force-fieldtrials=AutomaticTabDiscarding/Disabled`](https://crbug.com/525216#c17) as a commandline switch, following [these instructions](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags).

Comment: How can I check if tab discarding has been disabled, other than opening tons of tabs to try and trigger discards?

Comment: Use Chrome as your normally do, and at some point view the bottom of the chrome://discards/ page and hope it has '0 discards this session'.